# Why http request not working for webservice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Following code not working, but if I replaced the url with `data/fillMenu.json`, it works.

```
$http.get("http://192.168.11.217:9095/module/getmainmodules")
.then(function(response) {
  $sessionStorage.pr = response.data;
});
```

Comment: define "_not working_", what went wrong? Do you have any errors or no data arrives? consider catching an error response by expanding it as: `$http.get(url).then((response)=>{...}, (error)=>{...})`

Comment: Not the same site? Same origin policy?

Comment: if i replaced the url with json file which is present inside my netbeans project it is working

Comment: problem in your api i think

Comment: Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: the web service was developed in eclipe and my project is developed in netbeans,is it because of that???